# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object - PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am currently trying to learn Laravel and PHP in general.

I need to be able to import an Excel file, then get the data from that file. Currently, the import part works and I can see the data from the file. However, I am having trouble accessing the data.

I've read about the `toArray()` function in Laravel, and is using that as below:

```
 $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->skipColumns(2)->get();
 $data = $data->toArray();

         foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

           //We only need some of the available data.
           echo $value->next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd;
           echo $value->shipment_id;

          }
```

Above code gives me below error:

> **Trying to get property 'next_milestone_desc_cur' of non-object**

Below is an output from the array, which I have generated using `dd($value)`:

```
array:543 [▼
  0 => array:20 [▼
    "next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd" => "005. DK - Add DropMode/Local Trp Org in Pickup Tab"
    "milestone_cur._comp._sequence_no" => "005"
    "cur._comp._export_validation" => "NOT OK"
    "shipment_id" => "SBRY0162091"
    "consol_id" => "CDK327188"  ]
  1 => array:20 [▼
    "next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd" => "005. DK - Add DropMode/Local Trp Org in Pickup Tab"
    "milestone_cur._comp._sequence_no" => "005"
    "cur._comp._export_validation" => "NOT OK"
    "shipment_id" => "SBRY0162124"
    "consol_id" => "CDK327221"
  ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have also tried 
`echo $value[0]->next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd;`, however this doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe the dots. Try `$name = "next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd"; echo $value[0]->$name;` Dots in PHP signify concatenation (as JS and Python use "+")

Comment: What is `$value`? Do `var_dump` because as the error suggests, it isn't an object.

Comment: Laravel is vastly different to vanilla PHP so if you are using it to learn PHP, I would advise against it. Learn vanilla then Laravel.

Comment: @Script47 I am already doing the `dd($value)`. However when doing `var_dump($value)`, it returns `array(543) { [0]=> array(20) { ........ `

Comment: @oliverbj then you need to access the values as an array `$value[0]['key']`, not an object `$value->key`.

Comment: ^ @Script47 is right, I missed it's an array.

Comment: @Script47 But how should I then iterate through the array in my foreach? By doing `$i++` and looping through the array like `$value[$i]`?

Comment: You can use a nested loop.

Comment: @Script47 Would you mind providing an example? Sorry, but I want to get it right! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an array as an object hence your error and to address you second point, you need to use a nested loop to then access the sub-array.

Your array looks something like this:

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => [
      'test' => 'value'
    ],

    1 => [
      'test' => 'something'
    ]  
  ],

  1 => [
    0 => [
      'test' => 'value'
    ],

    1 => [
      'test' => 'something'
    ]  
  ]  
];
```

You need the following loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $nested) {
  foreach ($nested as $nested_value) {
    // You have access to your inner arrays.
    echo  $nested_value['test'] . ' | ';
  }
}
```

Where your nested loops `$nested` would be `$value`.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/NormalKosherLoopfusion)

Comment: This will allow me to access all the data in the loop. However, after the loop is finished Laravel will throw this error: `Undefined index: milestone_cur._comp._sequence_no`. Is this because some of the array items doesn't contain any data in `milestone_cur._comp._sequence_no`?

Comment: Yes, that error is thrown a specific key doesn't exist. You can use `array_key_exists` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your output from dd($value) shows that $value is an array. So you cannot use arrow notation that is for objects. Change these lines:

```
echo $value->next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd;
echo $value->shipment_id;
```

To:

```
echo $value[0]["next_milestone_desc_cur._comp._incl_rltd"];
echo $value[0]["shipment_id"];
```

Comment: But how do I loop through my array?

Comment: You need another foreach